# Python: incorporating index from for loop as part of a list name

Tags: python, list, indexing, for-loop

How does one generate a set of lists that incorporate the index from a for loop in the list name:

```
for j in range(10):
   li"j" = []
```

How can the index 'j' be part of the name, so the lists are li0, li1, li2, ...

Thanks!

Comment: whatever is your problem, this isn't probably the correct solution. consider using an additional container object rather than adding dynamically created variables from namespace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make `li` a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
li = {}
for j in range(10):
    li[j] = []
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do this simply to initialize lists to use them later, you should instead use *one* multi-dimensional list or even better tuple to do this:

```
li = tuple( [] for i in range( 10 ) )
li[0].append( 'foo' )
li[5].append( 'bar' )
```

Comment: Thanks to all for the ideas. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Jake, appreciation on StackOverflow generally takes the form of "upvoting" (click above vote counts) any answers you find helpful, and eventually accepting the best one (click on its checkmark). :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with exec, like so:

```
exec ("li%s = []" % 4)
```

But don't do this. You almost certainly do not want dynamically named variables. Greg Hewgill's approach will probably solve your problem.

Comment: I'd vote this up for the "don't do this" part, but even showing the exec option for a case like this deserves a downvote so they cancel out...

Comment: I'd prefer `locals()["li%s" % j] = []` to the exec call.  Because I'll always prefer a way that doesn't use exec or eval.